# Styling Opacity of Select Option Text

Tags: html, css

How can I style opacity of option text?

For example, I have:

```css
option:first-child {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="select-where" required>
  <option value="">Please choose on option</option>
  <option value="1">Friends and family</option>
  <option value="2">Youtube Video</option>
  <option value="3">Podcast</option>
  <option value="4">Facebood ad</option>
  <option value="5">Others</option>
</select>
```

which does not work.

Comment: Have you considered just using the [`disabled` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled), [demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mc9ugn2t/](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mc9ugn2t/)?

Comment: I like David's simple solution! 
It's a bit of a cheat, but the end result is similar, and it will definitely work in all browsers.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for the suggestion but first, it is not actually a way of styling the element, and second, if you disable it, you can set it as a default value.

Comment: Okay, so it is not possible to style, according to [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element). Then the remaining question is how to make it disabled and set it as default?